# Isomorphism between vector space and translation group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Hi Im trying to find an isomorphism between the group of translations of a vector space $V$ and the vector space itself with the addition $(V,+)$ In the exercise it is not precised if the addition $+$ is the canonic one but I guess so.

For my isomorphism, Im thinking of the application which simply associate to each vector $v$ of $V$ the translation $v$ (the translation which take a vector $u$ of $V$ and give $u+v$), but I think it is maybe too simple.

Comment: It is that simple, but you likely are supposed to justify in detail that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: How is the group of translations of $V$ defined, for the purposes of your exercise?

Comment: It is not defined explicitly, I guess we are supposed to know it, it must be how it is defined in general.

As quid said, I think the justification is really the exercise, I just wanted to know if I was not wrong because this is quite new for me.

Comment: Perhaps it is the isometry group of $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is a semidirect product of $O_n(\mathbb{R})$ and the group of translations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ - which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I think the translation group is $T(V) := \{f \colon V \to V \mid f(v) = v + b \text{ for some $b \in V$} \}$ (in this context you may also confer Cayley's Theorem).

Comment: @DietrichBurde I personally don't understand the content of your comment.

Comment: @M.U. Oh, this was just a guess about what the "purpose of the exercise" could be (see the comment of Lee Mosher). The exercise is sometimes used to determine the structure of $Isom(\mathbb{R}^n)$.